# Loading Objective C code dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-loading

I am looking for a possibility of loading Obj C based source dynamically and show the view in my iOS application. For example: I have a set of code written for showing a view, i want to dynamically load this code and show this view. 
Some thing like,

1. I'll have a service running in the background of my iOS app.
2. It will get a set of Obj C code from my server in text format
3. This dynamic Obj C code should get executed dynamically and show the respective iOS view

**From Comments** Not released in the appstore.. its for internal

Is this possible?

Comment: For release in the app store?

Comment: Not released in the appstore..its for internal.

Comment: Mind letting us know why you need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **No**

Not so short answer:

You could—in theory—include either the C, or C++ interface to the Clang compiler toolchain in your project, have that library compile the code you download, and then (through either NSBundle or direct interaction with dlopen) link that compiled code into your app.

In practice, if what you want to achieve is submitting to the App Store, this is explicitly prohibited by the Terms and Conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this for deployment to the app store.

You wouldn't use plain text for this, you'd use a bundle (`NSBundle`). A bundle can contain both file (graphics, NIBs) resources and code so you can create your view classes and any associated NIBs, compile the bundle and then store it on your server. The app can then download the bundle and load it at runtime.

Comment: This is good. Any reference that I can follow it? Another question, Can I make this process like compile and make the bundle, be Automated ? Is there any existing software to do this automatically, instead of manually do? Because I want everything should happen at run time and dynamically.

Comment: I wouldn't look at runtime compilation in the app, the bundle should be compiled when you write the code for it and then the compiled bundle is saved on the server for the app to download.

Comment: I won't write any code programmatically. Obj C based code will be generated(text format) through an automatic way thru a desktop tool and kept in server.

Comment: So that automatic tool should also compile the code before saving it on the server using the Xcode command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for non-app store apps.  I have not tried  this approach.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW14):

> The key to loading code from an external bundle is finding an
>   appropriate entry point into the bundle’s executable file. As with
>   other plug-in schemes, this requires some coordination between the
>   application developer and the plug-in developer. You can publish a
>   custom API for bundles to implement or define a formal plug-in
>   interface. In either case, once you have an appropriate bundle or
>   plug-in, you use the NSBundle class (or the CFBundleRef opaque type)
>   to access the functions or classes implemented by the external code.
>
> Loading Objective-C Classes If you are writing a Cocoa application,
>   you can load the code for an entire class using the methods of
>   NSBundle. The NSBundle methods for loading a class are for use with
>   Objective-C classes only and cannot be used to load classes written in
>   C++ or other object-oriented languages.

Comment: Thanks, 1. How do you say that it is allowed for Non App store apps only? 2.Can I have the process of compiling bundle and all dynamically to do with some automated process created?

Comment: App store guidelines states that Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972802/appstore-ios-apps-and-interpreted-code-where-do-they-draw-the-line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859724/what-kind-of-downloaded-code-violates-app-store-review-guideline