# Is there any way in Swift language that we can post compiled classes into the published program?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic-class-loaders

Is there any way in Swift language that we can post compiled classes into the published program and if new features are added to the program, or changes will be made?
Almost I want a program that does not require an update from the user's side and we will send new information directly to the program.

Comment: No – see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324374/loading-objective-c-code-dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Also it's bad idea.
Apple Review Team will reject your app due point "2.3 Accurate Metadata" of Apple Review guideline